# A group that has a $\frac{3}{2}$-transitive subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Do you know a group that has a $\frac{3}{2}$-transitive subgroup and it is not  $\frac{3}{2}$-transitive itself?

Answer (score 2):

I found this group using GAP.

Let

$$ \begin{align*}
a &= (29)(36)(48)(57)\\
b &= (136)(247)(589) \\
c &= (192)(354)(687).
\end{align*}$$

And let $H=\langle a,b,c\rangle$.  This is a $\frac{3}{2}$-transitive subgroup of $S_9$ (it is a Frobenius group, with kernel $\langle b,c\rangle$). It is contained in a larger group $G$, generated by $H$ and the two elements

$$ \begin{align*}
d &= (129) \\
e &= (12)(45)(78).
\end{align*}$$

This group, just like $H$, is transitive.  But the point stabilizer of $1$ only permutes $2$ and $9$ amongst themselves, while transitively moving the other $6$ points amongst themselves.  In other words, it is not $\frac{3}{2}$-transitive.

To clarify my search, I simply looked for transitive, but not primitive, subgroups of a symmetric group (I chose $S_9$ because neither $9$ nor $9-1$ is prime). I then looked in those groups for subgroups that were Frobenius (as all $\frac{3}{2}$-transitive groups are either Frobenius or primitive).

Comment: Magic $9$. $S_9$ was chosen cleverly. +1